# Validate 9 digits with dashes

Tags: jquery

I need to validate 9 digits with dashes(000-00-0000). How to do this with regular expression but it need to be that specific format
Example : 999-99-999, 585-25-555

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: use this ^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.●]?([0-9]{2})[-.●]?([0-9]{3})$

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the below function on Onblur event of Text box.This will validate the pattern (9 digits with dashes(000-00-0000) )

```
function validateSSN(element) {
        var isValidated = false;
        value = element.value;
        if(/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/i.test(value)) {
            isValidated = true;
        }
        if(!isValidated){
            alert('Please enter a valid SSN number.');
            $(element).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```